# absolute url of inline images in body using views and services

Tags: views, 8

I am using [services](https://www.drupal.org/project/services) module in Drupal 8 to output node body in JSON format. The inline images are broken in android app which uses json to render node. Is there any code/method or module for D8 which can rewrite relative inline images path to absolute. My drupal version is 8.0.5

Comment: `My drupal version is 8.0.5` you need to update to 8.2.5

Comment: These images are inside the body field? added through CKeditor?

Comment: Yes, added using default ckeditor

Comment: I tried using Pathologic and rel_to_abs modules, they are able to convert relative url to absolute in browser view but not in serialized JSON output.

Comment: does core REST API module also not help here? Probably you can write a views serializer plugin to alter JSON output like https://cgit.drupalcode.org/one_api/tree/src/Plugin/views/style/SerializerCount.php

Answer (score 2):

This is discussed for a long time, but unfortunately there is no solution committed to core until now, see https://www.drupal.org/node/2630076

Basically this tells you, that you need a text filter like this

http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/core/modules/editor/src/Plugin/Filter/EditorFileReference.php

where you change the line

```
$node->setAttribute('src', file_url_transform_relative(file_create_url($file->getFileUri())));
```

to

```
$node->setAttribute('src', file_create_url($file->getFileUri()));
```

by removing `url_transform_relative()`.

Comment: How to use this text filter file. My drupal version is 8.0.5 and I and not able to find url_transform_relative() function in EditorFileReference.php file.

Comment: Don't know if you have the data attributes you need in 8.0.5 - More information how to use and build text filters: https://www.lullabot.com/articles/creating-a-custom-filter-in-drupal-8

Comment: Is there any way to force ckeditor to use absolute url`s for inline images?

Comment: By default ckeditor adds `data-entity-uuid` to the link which helps to identify from which file it was generated. So no action is needed. You can check in ckeditor the html source, if your links have the data attribute. Then if you apply the text filter the url will be regenerated on each request.

Comment: Tried using text filters provided by Pathologic and rel_to_abs modules, they were able to regenerate relative url to absolute in browser view but not in serialized JSON output produced by services module. Text filters has no effect on JSON output, the only way is to force ckeditor to save absolute url of inline image while creating a node.

Comment: ... or a custom plugin for the service module. This might be better, because then you have the same logic for normal rendering and json.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post but I thought it will be helpful for anyone to know my solution for Drupal 9.

Here is the answer:

- Create a custom module
- Create a file "CustomEditorFileReference" in src/Plugin/Filter

Put the following code:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\complaints\Plugin\Filter;

use Drupal\Component\Utility\Html;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityRepositoryInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Image\ImageFactory;
use Drupal\Core\Plugin\ContainerFactoryPluginInterface;
use Drupal\file\FileInterface;
use Drupal\filter\FilterProcessResult;
use Drupal\filter\Plugin\FilterBase;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

/**
 * Provides a filter to track images uploaded via a Text Editor.
 *
 * Generates file URLs and associates the cache tags of referenced files.
 *
 * @Filter(
 *   id = "custom_editor_file_reference",
 *   title = @Translation("Track images uploaded via a Text Editor with absolut path"),
 *   description = @Translation("Ensures that the latest versions of images uploaded via a Text Editor are displayed with absolute path."),
 *   type = Drupal\filter\Plugin\FilterInterface::TYPE_TRANSFORM_REVERSIBLE
 * )
 */
class CustomEditorFileReference extends FilterBase implements ContainerFactoryPluginInterface {

  /**
   * The entity repository.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityRepositoryInterface
   */
  protected $entityRepository;

  /**
   * The image factory.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Image\ImageFactory
   */
  protected $imageFactory;

  /**
   * Constructs a \Drupal\editor\Plugin\Filter\EditorFileReference object.
   *
   * @param array $configuration
   *   A configuration array containing information about the plugin instance.
   * @param string $plugin_id
   *   The plugin_id for the plugin instance.
   * @param mixed $plugin_definition
   *   The plugin implementation definition.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityRepositoryInterface $entity_repository
   *   The entity repository.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Image\ImageFactory $image_factory
   *   The image factory.
   */
  public function __construct(array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition, EntityRepositoryInterface $entity_repository, ImageFactory $image_factory = NULL) {
    $this->entityRepository = $entity_repository;
    if ($image_factory === NULL) {
      @trigger_error('Calling ' . __METHOD__ . '() without the $image_factory argument is deprecated in drupal:9.1.0 and is required in drupal:10.0.0. See https://www.drupal.org/node/3173719', E_USER_DEPRECATED);
      $image_factory = \Drupal::service('image.factory');
    }
    $this->imageFactory = $image_factory;
    parent::__construct($configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition);
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition) {
    return new static(
      $configuration,
      $plugin_id,
      $plugin_definition,
      $container->get('entity.repository'),
      $container->get('image.factory')
    );
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function process($text, $langcode) {
    $result = new FilterProcessResult($text);

    if (stristr($text, 'data-entity-type="file"') !== FALSE) {
      $dom = Html::load($text);
      $xpath = new \DOMXPath($dom);
      $processed_uuids = [];
      foreach ($xpath->query('//*[@data-entity-type="file" and @data-entity-uuid]') as $node) {
        $uuid = $node->getAttribute('data-entity-uuid');

        // If there is a 'src' attribute, set it to the file entity's current
        // URL. This ensures the URL works even after the file location changes.
        if ($node->hasAttribute('src')) {
          $file = $this->entityRepository->loadEntityByUuid('file', $uuid);
          if ($file instanceof FileInterface) {
            $node->setAttribute('src', $file->createFileUrl(FALSE));
            if ($node->nodeName == 'img') {
              // Without dimensions specified, layout shifts can occur,
              // which are more noticeable on pages that take some time to load.
              // As a result, only mark images as lazy load that have dimensions.
              $image = $this->imageFactory->get($file->getFileUri());
              $width = $image->getWidth();
              $height = $image->getHeight();
              if ($width !== NULL && $height !== NULL) {
                if (!$node->hasAttribute('width')) {
                  $node->setAttribute('width', $width);
                }
                if (!$node->hasAttribute('height')) {
                  $node->setAttribute('height', $height);
                }
                if (!$node->hasAttribute('loading')) {
                  $node->setAttribute('loading', 'lazy');
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }

        // Only process the first occurrence of each file UUID.
        if (!isset($processed_uuids[$uuid])) {
          $processed_uuids[$uuid] = TRUE;

          $file = $this->entityRepository->loadEntityByUuid('file', $uuid);
          if ($file instanceof FileInterface) {
            $result->addCacheTags($file->getCacheTags());
          }
        }
      }
      $result->setProcessedText(Html::serialize($dom));
    }

    return $result;
  }

}
```

- Now go to the "Text formats and editors" page and edit the ones with
  CKeditor.
- Enable Track images uploaded via a Text Editor with absolute path
- Make sure that filter "Track images uploaded via a Text Editor" is the last one to execute

Comment: It works, but the filter "Track images uploaded via a Text Editor" must be the last one to execute. If it's the first, it doesn't work. Thank you so much!

Comment: I updated the answer to include your comments. Thanks :)